# Why does gcc warn when lambda parameter shadows private member of base class

Tags: c++, gcc, c++17, compiler-warnings

When enabling `-Wshadow` during compilation, why does gcc warn when the name of a parameter of a lambda defined in a derived class "shadows" the name of a private member variable of its base class? Example:

```
#include <iostream>

class Base {
private:
    int data;
};

class Derived: public Base {
public:
    void test(int val) {
        auto lambda = [](const auto& data) {};
        lambda(val);
    }
};
```

When compiling, gcc - tested with version 9.2 - shows (https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/bRmUzz):

```
<source>: In lambda function:
<source>:11:36: error: declaration of 'data' shadows a member of 'Derived' [-Werror=shadow]
   11 |   auto lambda = [](const auto& data) {};
      |                                    ^
<source>:5:6: note: shadowed declaration is here
    5 |  int data;
      |      ^~~~
```

Why does this generate a shadow warning and how to prevent it, without disabling `-Wshadow` altogether? `data` is private in the base class! Declaring a member variable called `data` in the derived class does not lead to such a warning, as expected.

Comment: This warning seems to be reasonable. Note that access specifiers are not controlling *visibility*.